# How to reliably extract text from camera with tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to reliably extract text, more specifically digits and their bounding boxes from a camera taking pictures of a mobile phone screen.
However I am getting mixed results, usually unable to find digits, or falsely detecting 5 as a 9.
I understand pre-processing is important for tesseract, but any additional tips on improving this would be nice.[test2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ubHC.png)

```
import re
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

src = cv2.imread('test2.png')
image = cv2.rotate(src, cv2.cv2.ROTATE_90_CLOCKWISE)
dim = (1920, 2560)
imager = cv2.resize(image, dim, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)


# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# noise removal
def remove_noise(image):
    return cv2.medianBlur(image, 5)

# thresholding
def thresholding(image):
    return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + 
    cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

gray = get_grayscale(imager)
#nois = remove_noise(gray)
thresh = thresholding(gray)

#invert to get black text on white background
gray = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh)

img = gray

word = '0123456789'

d = pytesseract.image_to_data(img, 
output_type=Output.DICT,config="-c 
tessedit_char_whitelist="+word)
keys = list(d.keys())

print (d)

words = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0','95.00']
i = 0

for text in d['text']:
    try:
        words.index(text)
        (x, y, w, h) = (d['left'][i], d['top'][i], d['width'] 
        [i], d['height'][i])
        img = cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    except:
        i=i
    i = i+1
#center_X = x + w/2
#center_Y = y + h/2
#print(center_X, center_Y)

dim = (480, 640)
imager = cv2.resize(img, dim)
cv2.imshow('img', imager)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Please post a [mre]. What are `get_grayscale`, `thresholding`, `whitelist`, etc.? What are possible, additional imports next to `cv2`, and `pytesseract`?

Comment: I am sorry, imports are: import cv2
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import Output